# Returning config.read() from function

Tags: python, configparser

I have a config.py which reads in multiple config files.

```
from ConfigParser import *

def zones_config():
  zones_config = ConfigParser()
  zones = zones_config.sections()
  zones_config.read('zones.ini'), zones

def settings_config():
  settings_config = ConfigParser()
  settings_config.read('settings.ini')
```

Then in my database.py file:

```
from utils.config import settings_config

settings_config()

#mysqbdb config
ip = settings_config.get('mysqldb', 'ip')
username = settings_config.get('mysqldb', 'username')
password = settings_config.get('mysqldb', 'password')
database = settings_config.get('mysqldb', 'database')
```

However I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`settings_config` is a function, and `.get()` is a method of the ConfigParser object. This should explain it more clearly:

```
def settings_config_function():
  settings_config_object = ConfigParser()
  settings_config_object.read('settings.ini')
  return settings_config_object
```

Then in database.py:

```
from utils.config import settings_config_function

config_object = settings_config_function()

#mysqbdb config
ip = config_object.get('mysqldb', 'ip')
username = config_object.get('mysqldb', 'username')
password = config_object.get('mysqldb', 'password')
database = config_object.get('mysqldb', 'database')
```

Edit:

I also recommend you call

```
settings_config_object = settings_config_function()
another_example_config_object = another_example_config_function()
```

once at the bottom of config.py and later just

```
from utils.config import settings_config_object, another_example_config_object
```

in any files that require the configs, so that you don't have to instantiate a new ConfigParser and read the config files for every module that uses the config.